# MongoDB constantly high cpu usage and terminate MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

After execution, mongodb is terminated after a few seconds.

Symptom..

CPU usage is maintained at about 300%, and then suddenly shuts down.

LOG...

```
2021-06-21T17:53:06.994+0900 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Successfully connected to 172.27.0.33:37002 (1 connections now open to 172.27.0.33:37002 with a 5 second timeout)
2021-06-21T17:53:23.575+0900 E STORAGE  [WTCheckpointThread] WiredTiger error (12) [1624265603:575279][12778:0x7f9a910a3700], file:depository/collection-15--3593471947205486528.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __posix_sync, 108: /mongodb/base/storage/node12/depository/collection-15--3593471947205486528.wt: handle-sync: fdatasync: Cannot allocate memory Raw: [1624265603:575279][12778:0x7f9a910a3700], file:depository/collection-15--3593471947205486528.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __posix_sync, 108: /mongodb/base/storage/node12/depository/collection-15--3593471947205486528.wt: handle-sync: fdatasync: Cannot allocate memory
2021-06-21T17:53:23.575+0900 E STORAGE  [WTCheckpointThread] WiredTiger error (-31804) [1624265603:575407][12778:0x7f9a910a3700], file:depository/collection-15--3593471947205486528.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __wt_panic, 520: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic Raw: [1624265603:575407][12778:0x7f9a910a3700], file:depository/collection-15--3593471947205486528.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __wt_panic, 520: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
2021-06-21T17:53:23.575+0900 F -        [WTCheckpointThread] Fatal Assertion 50853 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_util.cpp 409
2021-06-21T17:53:23.575+0900 F -        [WTCheckpointThread] 

***aborting after fassert() failure

2021-06-21T17:53:23.589+0900 F -        [WTCheckpointThread] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
```

The mongodb where this problem occurs is secondary. There is no problem with other mongodb's(repl-set )